# getting timeouts from spymemcached, using Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, memcached, spymemcached

I'm trying to configure to use spymemcached to retrieve data from a memcached server (tried both 1.2 and 1.4). I configured it with the values provided in their wiki here (http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/SpringIntegration). However, if I inject that bean  as a `MemcachedClient` into my class, every time I try to access the cache I get a timeout. My line of code is as simple as that:

```
        MyClass object = (MyClass) memcachedClient.get(cacheKey);
```

at this moment the value is not in the cache, but I would expect it to return null. Instead, all I'm getting is a CXF exception (this is a webservice), in which the cause is:

```
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value
  at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1003)
  at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1018)
```

No info in the logs (although I'm still trying to put them in DEBUG, as for now I see only spymemcached logs for INFO). Anyone had similar issues? I can access the memcached server via telnet and the get correctly returns `END`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was using the `BINARY` protocol. Switching to `TEXT` works fine. I guess the installed build of memcached didn't support this protocol - however it was not an easy catch!